# Python combine values of identical dictionaries without using looping

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of identical dictionaries:

```
my_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]
```

I need to get something like this:

```
a = [1, 4, 7]
b = [2, 5, 8]
c = [3, 6, 9]
```

I know how to do in using `for .. in ..`, but is there way to do it without looping?
If i do

```
a, b, c = zip(*my_list)
```

i`m getting

```
a = ('a', 'a', 'a')
b = ('b', 'b', 'b')
c = ('c', 'c', 'c')
```

Any solution?

Comment: If my answer helped, consider accept it by checking the mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract all the values in `my_list`.You could try:

```
my_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]
a, b, c = zip(*map(lambda d: d.values(), my_list))
print(a, b, c)

# (1, 4, 7) (2, 5, 8) (3, 6, 9)
```

---

Pointed out by @Alexandre,This work only when the dict is ordered.If you couldn't make sure the order, consider the answer of yatu.

Comment: The problem, is that with this approach, you rely on the original order in the dict, if you invert a and b in one of the dicts, it won't work anymore

Comment: Thank you. This is what i`m looking for.
Solved

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop to obtain the values from the inner dictionaries. Probably the most appropriate structure would be to have a dictionary, mapping the actual letter and a list of values. Assigning to different variables is usually not the best idea, as it will only work with the fixed amount of variables.

You can iterate over the inner dictionaries, and append to a `defaultdict` as:

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)
for d in my_list:
    for k,v in d.items():
        out[k].append(v)

print(out)
#defaultdict(list, {'a': [1, 4, 7], 'b': [2, 5, 8], 'c': [3, 6, 9]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `DataFrame` has just a factory method for this, so if you already have it as a dependency or if the input data is large enough:

```
import pandas as pd
my_list = ...
df = pd.DataFrame.from_rows(my_list)
a = list(df['a']) # df['a'] is a pandas Series, essentially a wrapped C array
b = list(df['b'])
c = list(df['c'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below. I believe that the version with a loop is much easier to read.

```
my_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]

# we assume that all dictionaries have the sames keys
a, b, c = map(list, map(lambda k: map(lambda d: d[k], my_list), my_list[0]))
print(a,b,c)
```